# Did Leibniz interpret his determinant as a volume function?

Tags: mathematics

It might look like not a serious question, since Leibniz discovered Cramer's rule (1684), so it makes much sense that he interpreted the determinant as an expansion factor for a volumetric element. I'm only asking if someone can give sources, references to works by Leibniz in which he gave this interpretation of the determinant concept.

Did Leibniz interpret his determinant as a volume function?

Comment: See Knobloch's studies, like: [Déterminants et élimination chez Leibniz](http://www.persee.fr/doc/rhs_0151-4105_2001_num_54_2_2116) (2001) with references.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like an excellent reference, but unfortunately i'm unable to read french. Can you extract a certain passage from this article that is relavant to my question? or otherwise, can you find an english translation of this article?

Comment: The paper is about several (partial) "versions" of the *signs rule*, culminating in the right one, equivalent to Cramer's rule: "Règle générale des signes (1684) : Deux termes qui se distinguent l'un de l'autre seulement par un nombre impair de transpositions des indices gauches ou droits ont des signes opposés. Ceux qui se distinguent l'un de l'autre par un nombre pair ont le même signe."

Comment: If follows a discussion of the newly introduced symbolism for what we today call: *determinant*. The context, is L's interest into *ars combinatoria* and systems of equations. Knobloch has published in 1980 a book (in German) and edited L's manuscripts on *Der Beginn der Determinantentheorie*.

Comment: In the paper there is no hints to L's "interpretations" of determinant.

Comment: At [Alain Lascoux's web page](http://phalanstere.univ-mlv.fr/~al/) you can find .pdf files of Thomas Muir's encyclopedic history of determinants up to the 1920s. This work is one of the most complete literature surveys ever written in mathematics, and it's definitely where I would begin looking.

Comment: Thanks for the reference but the chapter on leibniz (at the begining) is very short and not exhausting. I didnt find there something relavant to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When did people realize that the determinant of a matrix is actually the volume of a parallelepiped?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6090/when-did-people-realize-that-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-is-actually-the-volume)